# How to delete orddict in Erlang

Tags: dictionary, erlang

I want to be able to delete multiple keys in Erlang and also have a way to erase all dictionary.

I have tried so far:

```
X=[{1,2},{3,4}].
Deleted=orddict:fold(fun({K,V})->orddict:erase(K,X) end ,[],X).
```

How do i erase all the keys?Do i need to use an external variable in my case `X` in the `fun` -> `erase` method ?

Comment: Deleting all the keys is equivalent to creating a new empty dictionary, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you try in your code, you cannot erase a key in an orddict, but you can create a copy of it without the key.

If you want to remove all the keys, just do what @choroba says, create a new orddict.

If you want to remove multiple but not all keys, there are many ways to achieve what you want, I propose you a solution using the function take, from orddict library:

> take(Key, Orddict) -> {Value, Orddict1}
>
> | error
>
> Orddict = Orddict1 = orddict(Key, Value)
>
> Key = Value = term()
>
> This function returns value from dictionary and new dictionary without
>   this value. Returns error if the key is not present in the dictionary.

First you create a function that take as argument a key an a Dict and return a dict without the key (if it exists)

```
1> F = fun(X,Dict) ->  case orddict:take(X,Dict) of
1> {_,New} -> New;
1> error -> Dict
1> end
1> end.
#Fun<erl_eval.13.91303403>
```

*edit: I didn't check the orddict library, you can use the erase function replacing* `F` *with* `G = fun(X,Dict) -> orddict:erase(X,Dict) end.`

Then you can use this function with lists:fold/3 to "remove" in your dict all keys from a list:

```
2> O1 =orddict:from_list([{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}]).
[{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}]
3> O2 = lists:foldl(F,O1,[3,1]).
[{2,b},{4,d}]
4> O3 = lists:foldl(F,O1,[3,5]).
[{1,a},{2,b},{4,d}]
5>
```